# AWS Lambda Node.js function not throwing promise errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda

I'm am writing a node.js v18 module in AWS Lambda that uses promises. I have a promise function that I know if throwing an error, but Lambda doesn't run the catch statement, it just waits and times out. On my local machine, the catch portion runs. Both are running Node.js 18

To trouble shot, I'm using the following code.

```
'use strict';

console.log('pre');
function main(event){
  // fetch is available with Node.js 18
  console.log("Fetch");
  fetch("https://aws.amazon.com/")
  .then(res => {
    console.log("status", res.status);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log({err});
  });
  console.log('end');
};

export const handler = typeof(exports) == "object" ? main() : main;
```

I'm expecting the following output:

```
pre
Fetch
end
{
  err: TypeError: fetch failed
      at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11457:11)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
    cause: Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
        at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1540:34)
        at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
        at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:959:8)
        at ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:743:12) {
      code: 'UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY'
    }
  }
}
```

I receive the above error when I run locally, but when I run this in AWS Lambda I receive the following:

```
2023-06-20T18:49:37.377Z    undefined   INFO    pre
START RequestId: 8f331a94-66bf-4d0a-8e8c-7906713e9652 Version: $LATEST
2023-06-20T18:49:37.382Z    8f331a94-66bf-4d0a-8e8c-7906713e9652    INFO    Fetch
2023-06-20T18:49:37.996Z    8f331a94-66bf-4d0a-8e8c-7906713e9652    INFO    end
2023-06-20T18:49:47.394Z 8f331a94-66bf-4d0a-8e8c-7906713e9652 Task timed out after 10.01 seconds
```

The function never advances with the promise and just times out. I have also tried using an async function and a try/catch block, and I get the same results.

What am I doing wrong that Lambda is not moving forward with the promise?

Comment: You've connected the Lambda function to a VPC and have no network route to the public internet, at a guess. Don't configure a VPC for your Lambda function.